# Regular expression to find a number ends with special character in Swift

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I have an array of strings like:

```
"Foo", "Foo1", "Foo$", "$Foo", "1Foo", "1$", "20$", "1$Foo", "12$$",  etc.
```

My required format is `[Any number without dots][Must end with single $ symbol]` (I mean, 1$ and 20$ from the above array)

I have tried like the below way, but it's not working.

```
func isValidItem(_ item: String) -> Bool {
   let pattern = #"^[0-9]$"#
   return (item.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil)
}
```

Can some one help me on this? Also, please share some great links to learn about the regex patterns if you have any.

Thank you

Comment: I know nothing about swift but wouldnt it have to be `^[0-9]+\$$`?

Comment: With `#"^[0-9]$"#` aren't you allowing only ONE digit? Maybe `^\d+$` do the trick? Do not hesitate to use an online regex like http://regex101.com to test your regex and then apply it on Swift.

Comment: ``#"^[0-9]+\$$"#`` or better - ``#"^[0-9]+\$\z"#``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```swift
func isValidItem(_ item: String) -> Bool {
   let pattern = #"^[0-9]+\$\z"#
   return (item.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil)
}

let arr = ["Foo", "Foo1", "Foo$", "$Foo", "1Foo", "1$", "20$", "1$Foo", "12$$"]

print(arr.filter {isValidItem($0)})
// => ["1$", "20$"]
```

Here,

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `[0-9]+` - one or more ASCII digits (note that [Swift regex engine is ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) and `\d` matches any Unicode digits in this flavor, so `[0-9]` is safer if you need to only match digits from the `0-9` range)
- `\$` - a `$` char
- `\z` - the very end of string.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1dMbK1/1) (`$` is used instead of `\z` since the demo is run against a single multiline string, hence the use of the `m` flag at regex101.com).